# Objective-C compare 2 dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

I would like to make an app where you get coins ever day.
How can i make a timer or something else who ckecks, wether the user already got the coin?
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What have you tried, your question is one that you could have easily found by reading the docs or google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the time that the user got the coin in the user defaults.
Every time the application enter from the background check if the timeToGetAnotherCoin has passed.